# Error getting while trying to import a .jws file in Jdeveloper

Tags: soa, jdeveloper

I have an existing SOA Code base which is having the .jws file. when i'm trying to open the project using the Open Application option and selecting the .jws file it's giving me following error. My Jdev version is 11.1.1.9.0 and jdk is 1.6.

[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLVhX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update your JDev version, because it says that the workspace you are trying to open is already migrated to newer version which is 11.1.2.0.0. Just update your JDeveloper and try again.